# Get Bitcoind Node Login Info (rpc,port,ip)

Tags: php, node.js, bitcoind

I work on an Laravel PHP Script and i must connect the script with Bitcoin / bitcoind Full Node. Its the first time that i work with Bitcoind.

Maybe its an silly question but where i get my Connection login info to my Bitcoind Node Server??

I have installed the Full Node on an Ubuntu VPS Server from here: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1610

Now my script needs this info to connect to Bitcoind Server:

```
BITCOIND_HOST:
BITCOIND_PORT:
BITCOIND_USERNAME:
BITCOIND_PASSWORD:
```

i have create on my Bitcoind Server in the .bitcoin folder the file bitcoin.conf

with this info:

```
prune=600
maxconnections=125
maxuploadtarget=0
rpcuser=test
rpcpassword=test
daemon=1
keypool=50000
```

The Script and Bitcoind runs on differant Servers.

Its correct to fill out it with this info?:

```
BITCOIND_HOST: My VPS IP Address
BITCOIND_PORT: ??? i dont know
BITCOIND_USERNAME:test
BITCOIND_PASSWORD:test
```

Its correct that if the bitcoind runs on an other server as the script, thats not encrypted and can be leaked?

I search now for weeks and dont find mutch on google.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> BITCOIND_PORT: ??? i dont know

Runnng bitcoind you can pass port parameter as documented here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

```
-port=<port>    Listen for connections on <port> (default: 8333 or testnet: 18333)
```

If you didn't pass any `port` parameter, it is 8333 by default. You can also define port in bitcoin.conf too in this way:

```
rpcport=8332
```

> Its correct that if the bitcoind runs on an other server as the script, thats not encrypted and can be leaked?

Be careful if you want to run a bitcoind service on public interface and it is visible on internet! If you want to do such thing, don't trust just using user/password. Best practice is to use your bitcoind server **firewall** setting to just allow your PHP server ip to be connected to your bitcoind port. You can also use bitcoin.conf to limit the ip address which can connect to your bitcoin rpc, with `rpcallowip` variable.